# Set auto complete to match case

Tags: auto-complete-mode

Prelude has enabled a lot of very useful features, esp. auto complete. For some reason auto complete uses only lower case letters, which is not very helpful with camel-case class or function names.

For example, given the function name handleNewMessage, auto complete suggests handlenewmessage:

[image]

How can I get suggestions in camel case?